# struct as key of unordered_map

Tags: c++

I have a problem putting data into an unordered_map using a struct as key:

```
typedef struct osdpi_flow_identificator {
 u32 lower_ip;
 u32 upper_ip;
 u16 lower_port;
 u16 upper_port;
 u8 protocol;
} osdpi_flow_identificator_t;

// custom hash function for osdpi_flow_identificator
struct osdpi_flow_hash {
 std::size_t operator() (osdpi_flow_identificator * key) const {
  hash hash_function;
  std::size_t returnValue =
   hash_function(key->lower_ip)
   + hash_function(key->upper_ip)
   + hash_function(key->lower_port)
   + hash_function(key->upper_port)
   + hash_function(key->protocol);

  printf(" calculated hash: %i\n", returnValue);

  return returnValue;
 }
};

typedef unordered_map <osdpi_flow_identificator*, osdpi_flow*, osdpi_flow_hash> osdpi_flows_hashmap;
typedef osdpi_flows_hashmap::value_type osdpi_flows_pair;
static osdpi_flows_hashmap osdpi_flows;
```

My problem is that the hash function returns the same value for osdpi_flow_identificators having the same value, but

```
 osdpi_flow_identificator * flow_id = new osdpi_flow_identificator;
 osdpi_flows_hashmap::const_iterator iter;
 iter = osdpi_flows.find(flow_id);
 if (iter != osdpi_flows.end()) {
  ...
```

doesn't find it, although an entry with a flow_id having exactly the same values, is already in the hash map. I verified it, by outputting the whole hash map and also the hash function prints out the same value. So it's quite hard for me to understand, why unordered_map can't find the entry with the same hash.

I also tried to overload operator== and operator<, which I sometimes found as tip in the net, but those functions also were not called.

What solves the issue, but, of course, later ends up with a segmentation fault, is to leave flow_id uninitialized - then the entry can be found correctly.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks
Steffen

Comment: This is obviously wrong :
typedef unordered_map osdpi_flows_hashmap;

Could you please write the right template parameters of unordered_map ?

Comment: Thanks, Scharron. Sorry.. less/greater than signs were stripped. Replaced them now with &lt; and &gt;

Comment: FYI, first, the hash function is called on your key, then if some objects exist with the same hash, operator== is called.
operator< is only called with std::map (ordered maps).

Comment: Thanks for clarification! So I have to overload ==? But even when I overload it, the function isn't called at all:
typedef struct osdpi_flow_identificator {
...
bool operator==(osdpi_flow_identificator& other) {
    printf("operator==() called\n");
    return true;
}

Comment: no, you don't need that. There exists a default operator== on structs, applying == on all fields. This should suit your needs.
As I said, it's only called when there is a hash collision.

Comment: I made a mistake. Even if there is no collision, it must call operator== since it cannot know if the element found is the good one.

My answer is coming ;-)

Comment: So do you have an idea, while I can't find the elements? I get an output (because of the printf in the hash function), while searching for the entry and afterwards a new entry (with the same hash) is inserted again - and why the mystery that it works, when I don't initialize flow_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally found it :-)

In fact you need to define an EqualOperator for your hash, since you are using pointers.
It should be something like :

```
struct Eq
{
  bool operator() ( osdpi_flow_identificator * id1, osdpi_flow_identificator * id2) const
  {
    id1->lower_ip == id2->lower_ip && // compare all fields.
  }
};
```

then your hashmap declaration becomes

```
typedef unordered_map <osdpi_flow_identificator*, osdpi_flow*, osdpi_flow_hash, Eq> osdpi_flows_hashmap;
```

Another way to do it is to store objects in the hashmap, instead of pointers. It depends if you really want pointers in it.

Comment: Yeah, cool.. made my day/week :)
Had to declare the operator() function as const: bool operator() (...) const {..}, otherwise it failed with: "error: passing ‘const osdpi_flow_equal’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘bool osdpi_flow_equal::operator()(osdpi_flow_identificator*, osdpi_flow_identificator*)’ discards qualifiers". Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you use the builtin operator though? Something like `return *id1 == *id2;`.

Comment: @Mark B: Yes, but then I have to overload operator==() with the code I currently have in Eq::operator(). So not fewer code, but it might be a bit cleaner IMHO, yes.